# Java: ThreadLocal get() method alternative

Tags: java-8, thread-local

I was wondering, is there an elegant way to get the Threadlocal initialValue?
The reason I'm asking this is because I'm converting a non thread safe project into a thread safe one, problem is, there are nearly a thousand different class fields that cannot be shared between all threads and must be exclusive to each thread, thus using ThreadLocal solves that.

Problem is once fields are converted to ThreadLocal, on every field usage in the code , I must add a .get() to it which will probably take me light years to accomplish.

**For example:**

Declare the field:

```
private ThreadLocal<String> field1 = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

initialize the field:

```
field1.set("input");
```

print the field:

```
System.out.println("field1 = "+field1.get());
```

there must be an IDE shortcut that probably solves that.

But thinking about code appearance, code meaning, elegance and future development, My Goal with this post is to know if there's an elegant way of achieving the ThreadLocal's field value just like in C# where you have a field property that you can wrap it the way you desire, and by simply typing down the field's name you're getting it's value

**What I wish to achieve:**

Declare the field:

```
private ThreadLocal<String> field1 = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

initialize the field:

```
field1.set("input");
```

An elegant wrapper:

```
{some ThreadLocal.get() property wrapper}
```

print the field:

```
System.out.println("field1 = "+field1);
```

Overall, I'm for somewhat reason not satisfied at all with the .get() solution..

Any suggestions?

Comment: If even pressing the `Shift` key when writing the `T` of `ThreadLocal` is too much work for you, I’m afraid, there is no help. I first thought, you were talking about the initial value, for which an alternative exists, but then, you are only saying that you dislike saying `get` when you want to *get* the value, seriously?

Comment: Regarding the capital T's , my shift key isn't a hundred percent, nevertheless I'm also allergic to lazy typers..

Comment: Regarding the main idea behind this thread, well @Holger, we all see things differently, I'm going through many scenarios where .get() comes after another .get() method, which kinda feels redundant, My question still stands, is there a way to get the value with only specifying the threadlocal's field name?

Comment: Well, I understand that some people prefer to replace, e.g. `getFoo().getBar().getBaz()` with `foo.bar.baz`, but I don’t see, how you want to replace `.get().get().get()`. A sole `get()` could be elided without loosing information, but what should the syntax and behavior be when “.get() comes after another .get() method”? If all these `get()` calls stem from thread local variables, you are likely overusing them.

Comment: was referring to a different object with an unrelated get method,my  question still stands

Comment: Well, the “different object with an unrelated get method” is irrelevant to your question about `ThreadLocal` only. If there was a way to elide *this* `get()` invocation of your question, it would only elide the `get()` invocation of the `ThreadLocal` and nothing else, i.e. not the unrelated `get()` method(s). If that makes a difference in your source code, you are most probably calling `ThreadLocal.get()` too often. And why should there be a `ThreadLocal` specific possibility to elide the accessor call, of all the accessor method invocations out there?